# Calculation a closed form for the sum

Tags: combinatorics

Please help me to calculate this sum in a closed form:
$$
\sum\limits_{1\ \leq\ i_{1}\ <\ i_{2}\ <\ \cdots\ <\ i_{k}\ \leq\ n}
\left(i_{1} + i_{2} + \cdots + i_{k}\right).
$$
Here $n$, $k$ are positive integer numbers; $k < n$.

I think that it may be reduce to binomial coefficients, but I cannot understand how to do this.

Thank you very much in advance for your help !.

Comment: is your $k$ fixed or summing form $k=1$ to $k=n-1$?

Comment: $k$ is fixed. I mean
$$
\sum\limits_{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k):\,\,1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_k\leq n}(i_1+i_2+\ldots+i_k).
$$

Answer (score 2):

The sum 
$$
\sum_{j} i_j
$$
can be computed alternatively by counting how many times for $i_j=x$ appeared; the answer is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$: fix $x$, there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose other $k-1$ numbers from $\{1,\cdots,n\}\backslash \{x\} $. Therefore, the sum is simply
$$
\sum_{x} x\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+1}{2}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$

Comment: I don't see how the answer for how many times $i_j = x$ appeared could be independent of $x$ and also given by such an easy formula. Can you explain? It seems like $i_j = n$ should happen less frequently than $i_j = n/2$ for example.

Comment: @user2566092 No, everyone is equal. We just pick out $k$ numbers randomly from $\{1,\cdots, n\}$.

Comment: @user2566092 If you still have double, consider Vandermonde's identity, counting $x$ appears to the first, second, etc, together.

Comment: I still don't see how you get ${{n-1} \choose {k-1}}$. If you justified that step then I think you would get upvotes and get accepted by the OP as the answer. Your final answer is a polynomial of degree $k+1$, which my answer said must be the case. So it's possible your answer is correct. But how do you get ${{n-1} \choose {k-1}}$?

Comment: @user2566092 fix $x$, there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose other $k-1$ numbers from $\{1,\cdots,n\}\backslash \{x\} $.

Comment: I didn't see the strict inequalities in between the $i_j$. With those strict inequalities, then your reasoning is correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k+1$, so if nothing else you can just figure out the answer for $n = 1,2,\ldots,k+1$ and then solve for the polynomial coefficients that fit the polynomial, and thus get the answer for any fixed $k$. Alternatively you can solve for $k$ in increasing order using the recurrence below. Anyway, to see the answer is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k+1$, note that for $k=1$ you get $\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$ which is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $2$. Then, for $k \geq 1$, let $P_k(n)$ be the polynomial of degree $k+1$ that is the answer for $k,n$. Then by choosing the last number $i_{k+1}$ to be between $1$ and $n$, we see that $P_{k+1}(n) = \sum_{m=1}^n P_k(m)$ which is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k+2$ because $\sum_{m=1}^n m^{k'}$ for any power $k'$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k'+1$, by theorem. This gives an alternate way to compute the polynomial $P_{k+1}(n)$, if you write $P_k(m)$ as a sum of basis polynomials that you can easily sum from $m = 1$ to $n$.